# Run IONIC app on iframe of another framework

Tags: angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, sapui5

Can i render/run ionic app on an IFrame HTML element which is placed in an app hosted on a server.
If that's possible, can you suggest how do I need to include IONIC/Angular libraries in my framework.

As an example, can I render ionic app on view of SAPUI5 application?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [HTML control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.core.HTML/samples), you can include custom HTML into your application. This might be sufficient to include your Ionic application and already do the job.

If the HTML control doesn't give you enough freedom or flexibility, you may want to build a custom control that injects the right HTML code into your application. As an added advantage, you could e.g. expose properties such as with and height to be able to defined the screen real estate consumed by the Ionic application. [Step 34](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db.html) in the OpenUI5 walk-though will give you a good overview of how to build custom controls.

Comment: I did that in openUI5 using below code:-

new sap.ui.core.HTML({
      preferDOM: true,
      content: "<iframe width=100% height=100% src='file:///C:/Users/rohit.aneja/connectApps/www/index.html'></iframe>"
    })

But it did not render anything in IFrame.

Comment: Did you get an error message? I think you should have a CORS type error in the console section of your chrome debugging tools now. Both apps need to live on the same server.